# Error occured while inserting bulk data by using linq {Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.}

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, console-application

In this application, we are using 1,400,000 data by using SQL server. I am using Linq with SQL to insert 1,300,000 rows of data into a table, but it shows error at 1,143,234 rows and its exception is **Exception of type `System.OutOfMemoryException` was thrown**. I don't understand why it happened. I tried:

1. Delete the temp folder data.
2. I used clean too.

even then I get this error. If any one knows about this, please tell me.

Comment: We need little bit more than this. Code you use, for example. That said...what "lac" is???

Comment: When you are running the code, check your task manager for the available memory.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/909678

Comment: Well...are you sure you're not really running out of memory? For example...do you dispose disposable objects on each insert or you let them to GC? Which process is using too much RAM? You need to investigate by yourself a little bit...

Comment: @ShaktiPrakashSingh  I check the available memory to and  my c drive memory is 9 Gb left even then it  Give error to me.. thanks for rpy me tell me any thing more ???

Comment: @Adriano I am not using dispose for each insert but I used clear for this then i think it clear all the stuff.. rest of think You can tell me  is it ok or not?? or tell me other way to get it

Comment: @GURPREETSINGH it's hard to **guess** if there is something wrong, you should post some code, at least relevant parts. 9 GB aren't so much but what about RAM? That exception is for **free RAM**, not for disk.

Comment: @Adriano thank you so much for rpy . but now  its working.i Do the same think bu using bulk query and its giving fine result.. any way thanku so much for you support..

Comment: @GURPREETSINGH happy to hear that! so bad I didn't think about bulk inserts!

Comment: actually I used bulk already but i get the error at that time then if i get error from linq then I go back to my bulk query  and get the result.. thanku so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a pretty big SQL transaction building up there. Instead of adding all in one go, do a SaveChanges() every 5000 or 100000, or whatever interval seems to work.